# C Code For loop with nested If; modulus and sqrt issue

Tags: c, if-statement, nested-loops, modulus, sqrt

So, I am trying to get this C code to work.  It compiles, but produces incorrect outputs.  It should list all pefect square numbers between 1 and a chosen value.
It is doing something wrong, and after alot of trial and error i think the issue is with the modulus operation...like its truncating early or doing some other strange thing.

```
// C Code


/*This program will identify all square numbers between one and a chosen integer*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

int i, upper, square_int;
float square;
printf("This program will identify all square numbers between one and a chosen integer");

printf("Please enter the upper limit integer:");
scanf("%d", &upper);

upper = 13; /*scanf is the primary integer input method; this is here just to test it on codepad*/

for (i = 1; i<= upper; ++i) /*i want to run through all integers between 1 and the value of upper*/
{ 
    square = sqrt(i);  /* calc square root for each value of i */
    square_int = square;  /* change the root from float to int type*/

    if (i % (int)square_int == 0) /*check if i divided by root leaves no remainder*/
        printf("%d\n", i);  /*print 'em*/
}
printf("This completes the list of perfect squares between 1 and %d",upper);

return 0; /*End program*/
}
```

The output on codepad is:

```
This program will identify all square numbers between one and a chosen integerPlease enter the upper limit integer:1
2
3
4
6
8
9
12
This completes the list of perfect squares between 1 and 13
```

Which is of course wrong.  I expect to get 1, 2, 4 and 9 back.  Can anyone point out my screw up here?

Comment: "I expect to get 1, 2, 4 and 9 back" -> 2 is not a perfect square.

Comment: The square_int=square cast is messing up your algorithm concept. I think you know this is dodgy though because you are casting square_int as an int again later on.

Comment: right, meant to just write 1, 4 and 9.  Thanks.

Comment: If you can't understand what happens, why not just print all the values for debugging. (With `printf`.) Then you must see what goes not as expected by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler algorithm

```
int i = 1;
while (i*i < upper)
{
    printf("%d\n", i*i);
    ++i;
}
```

Another method is computing the square root, convert it to int, and compare the numbers.

```
for (i = 1; i <= upper; ++i)
{
    square = sqrt(i);
    square_int = square;
    if (square == (float)square_int)
        printf("%d\n", i );
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand why to use a float variable in between.  why don't do just `int sqroot = sqrt(i);` as **sqrt(3)** returns a `double`, it will be converted to `int` to store in the `sqroot` variable.

Comment: @luis because in this alorithm I compare the float (or double) with the int. We could also have squared the int and see if it's equal to i. This would be another algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Your modulo operation is incorrect. In case of `i = 6` `square_int` will become `2` and thus `i % (int)square_int` is equal to `6 % 2` which leads to `0`.

You could check if `square_int * square_int == i` instead.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  Was testing and implementing the code from chmike and didnt notice the extra posts.  It works now, got it spitting out exactly what I wanted.

Comment: BTW, i dont know where the heck i was going with the modulus...made some scribble notes in my morning meeting and started working the code right after.  THis is waht happens when you skip the data test phase... thanks for picking me up off the floor today guys.

Answer (score 1):

You says you expect to get `1, 2, 4, 9` which means you don't expect to get `3`.

Let's see with `i == 3`:

`sqrt(3) == 1.732051`

`(int) 1.732051 == 1`

`3 % 1 == 0`.

Which means it actually does what it is expected to do but it will not check if a number is a square.

A simple algorithm to check if the number is a square is to do:

```
sqrt_int = sqrt(i) + 0.5;

if (square_int * square_int  == i)
    printf("%d\n", i);
```